# How i get taxes info YQ in amadeus webservice Fare_MasterPricerTravelBoardSearch?

Tags: xml, amadeus

i neeed to get taxinfo using service Fare_MasterPricerTravelBoardSearch but the service is not returning that info. could do you help

request

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Fare_MasterPricerTravelBoardSearch xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <numberOfUnit xmlns="http://xml.amadeus.com/FMPTBQ_20_2_1A">
        <unitNumberDetail>
            <numberOfUnits>1</numberOfUnits>
            <typeOfUnit>PX</typeOfUnit>
        </unitNumberDetail>
        <unitNumberDetail>
            <numberOfUnits>40</numberOfUnits>
            <typeOfUnit>RC</typeOfUnit>
        </unitNumberDetail>
    </numberOfUnit>
    <paxReference xmlns="http://xml.amadeus.com/FMPTBQ_20_2_1A">
        <ptc>IT</ptc>
        <traveller>
            <ref>1</ref>
        </traveller>
    </paxReference>
    <fareOptions xmlns="http://xml.amadeus.com/FMPTBQ_20_2_1A">
        <pricingTickInfo>
            <pricingTicketing>
                <priceType>XND</priceType>
                <priceType>MST</priceType>
                <priceType>RP</priceType>
                <priceType>RU</priceType>
                <priceType>ET</priceType>
                <priceType>XLC</priceType>
                <priceType>TAC</priceType>
                <priceType>CUC</priceType>
                <priceType>NAD</priceType>
            </pricingTicketing>
        </pricingTickInfo>
        <feeIdDescription>
            <feeId>
                <feeType>FFI</feeType>
                <feeIdNumber>3</feeIdNumber>
            </feeId>
            <feeId>
                <feeType>BYQ</feeType>
                <feeIdNumber>2</feeIdNumber>
            </feeId>
        </feeIdDescription>
        <conversionRate>
            <conversionRateDetail>
                <currency>COP</currency>
            </conversionRateDetail>
        </conversionRate>
    </fareOptions>
    <itinerary xmlns="http://xml.amadeus.com/FMPTBQ_20_2_1A">
        <requestedSegmentRef>
            <segRef>1</segRef>
        </requestedSegmentRef>
        <departureLocalization>
            <departurePoint>
                <locationId>BOG</locationId>
            </departurePoint>
        </departureLocalization>
        <arrivalLocalization>
            <arrivalPointDetails>
                <locationId>IST</locationId>
            </arrivalPointDetails>
        </arrivalLocalization>
        <timeDetails>
            <firstDateTimeDetail>
                <date>200324</date>
            </firstDateTimeDetail>
        </timeDetails>
    </itinerary>
</Fare_MasterPricerTravelBoardSearch>
```

node recommendation response

```
<recommendation xmlns="http://xml.amadeus.com/FMPTBR_20_2_1A">
        <itemNumber>
            <itemNumberId>
                <number>1</number>
            </itemNumberId>
        </itemNumber>
        <fareFamilyRef>
            <referencingDetail>
                <refQualifier>F</refQualifier>
                <refNumber>1</refNumber>
            </referencingDetail>
        </fareFamilyRef>
        <recPriceInfo>
            <monetaryDetail>
                <amount>4698770</amount>
            </monetaryDetail>
            <monetaryDetail>
                <amount>1561770</amount>
            </monetaryDetail>
        </recPriceInfo>
        <segmentFlightRef>
            <referencingDetail>
                <refQualifier>S</refQualifier>
                <refNumber>1</refNumber>
            </referencingDetail>
            <referencingDetail>
                <refQualifier>B</refQualifier>
                <refNumber>1</refNumber>
            </referencingDetail>
        </segmentFlightRef>
        <paxFareProduct>
            <paxFareDetail>
                <paxFareNum>1</paxFareNum>
                <totalFareAmount>4698770</totalFareAmount>
                <totalTaxAmount>1561770</totalTaxAmount>
                <codeShareDetails>
                    <transportStageQualifier>V</transportStageQualifier>
                    <company>TK</company>
                </codeShareDetails>
                <codeShareDetails>
                    <company>GP</company>
                </codeShareDetails>
            </paxFareDetail>
            <paxReference>
                <ptc>IT</ptc>
                <traveller>
                    <ref>1</ref>
                </traveller>
            </paxReference>
            <fare>
                <pricingMessage>
                    <freeTextQualification>
                        <textSubjectQualifier>PEN</textSubjectQualifier>
                        <informationType>70</informationType>
                    </freeTextQualification>
                    <description>TICKETS ARE NON-REFUNDABLE</description>
                </pricingMessage>
            </fare>
            <fare>
                <pricingMessage>
                    <freeTextQualification>
                        <textSubjectQualifier>LTD</textSubjectQualifier>
                        <informationType>40</informationType>
                    </freeTextQualification>
                    <description>LAST TKT DTE</description>
                    <description>15FEB24</description>
                    <description> - SEE ADV PURCHASE</description>
                </pricingMessage>
            </fare>
            <fare>
                <pricingMessage>
                    <freeTextQualification>
                        <textSubjectQualifier>APM</textSubjectQualifier>
                        <informationType>5</informationType>
                    </freeTextQualification>
                    <description>NOT FARED AT PASSENGER TYPE REQUESTED *5*</description>
                </pricingMessage>
            </fare>
            <fareDetails>
                <segmentRef>
                    <segRef>1</segRef>
                </segmentRef>
                <groupOfFares>
                    <productInformation>
                        <cabinProduct>
                            <rbd>Q</rbd>
                            <cabin>M</cabin>
                            <avlStatus>9</avlStatus>
                        </cabinProduct>
                        <fareProductDetail>
                            <fareBasis>QY3PXOW</fareBasis>
                            <passengerType>ADT</passengerType>
                            <fareType>RP</fareType>
                        </fareProductDetail>
                        <breakPoint>Y</breakPoint>
                    </productInformation>
                    <fareFamiliesRef>
                        <referencingDetail>
                            <refQualifier>F</refQualifier>
                            <refNumber>1</refNumber>
                        </referencingDetail>
                    </fareFamiliesRef>
                </groupOfFares>
                <majCabin>
                    <bookingClassDetails>
                        <designator>M</designator>
                    </bookingClassDetails>
                </majCabin>
            </fareDetails>
        </paxFareProduct>
    </recommendation>
```

i see request with method `pricingTicketing`, in this version 20. i can use YQR but i do not understand how it use that. if you can give me an idea, it would be great, thank you very much.

Comment: You need to make a HTTP Request for a tax type and then get the request.  The different types of data is shown here (some are taxes) : https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/tmconsulting/amadeus-ws-go/sdk/fare/masterPricerTravelBoardSearch/v14_3_reply   You need to send a tax structure structure in the request to get a tax response.  Here is source code for one of the tax structure types : https://github.com/ArtisanCloud/PowerWeChat/blob/v3.1.22/src/payment/tax/request/requestCardTemplate.go

Comment: For Enterprise related questions get in touch directly with your account manager who would be able to provide you support.